# Use rand() or rdrand to generate a less biased random number in [0, 511]?

Tags: c, random

I'd like to generate a random number in the range [0, 511] using [rand()](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/ISO-Random.html) or [rdrand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDRAND) instruction.

Which method produces a less biased number?

For [example](https://godbolt.org/z/nrr6Yce7z),

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {

    srand(time(0));
    printf("rand [0,511]: %u\n",  rand() % 512);

    unsigned int num = 0;
    asm volatile("rdrand %0\n" "and $511,%0\n" : "=r" (num));
    printf("rdrand [0,511]: %u\n", num);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The implementation of `rand` is up the compiler, so your question is unanswerable as asked. But if you care about its bias, you're probably making a mistake by using it. (And that's an awful seed!) (I don't know anything about `rdrand`. But from the docs you linked, it sounds like it's top notch.)

Comment: I'm about to be of the opinion of throw rand() out and call the rdrand instruction and be done with worrying about any other way.

Comment: Probably better to use `_rdrand32_step()` from `<immintrin.h>` then inline assembly. (And compile with `-mrdrnd` if using gcc or clang)

Comment: @Shawn. Thanks for that intrinsic tip. Aside, does `rand()%(2^n)` also produce an unbiased number? In my case n=9, i.e., 2^9 = 512.

Comment: @vengy - it seems your question was closed before  you got a complete answer.  It seems to me that not only were you looking for a method to generate a random number in a range, but you also wanted to know how to test for even distribution (no bias -or- which method has less bias).  Am I right?  It's a shame because I coded a solution that addresses that second part.  I intend to post a link to the code here in the comments when I've polished it up, if you are interested.

Comment: @vengy - [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Kdh851167) is the code for testing bias of competing random number generators.

Comment: @vengy `rand()%(2^n)` is fine as long as `RAND_MAX` is a power-of-2 - 1, `(2^n) -1 <= RAND_MAX` and `(2^n)` does not exceeds `INT_MAX`.